# Installing pip using ArcGIS-installed Python 2.7

Tags: python, scrapy, pip, arcgis

I'm trying to install Scrapy for Python 2.7 on Windows 8.1 and I understand that I first need pip to be installed.  Since I have Python installed through ArcGIS 10.2, I think that I need to install pip under C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages.  Once pip is installed in that directory I receive the error code:

```
>>> import pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip.util import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.distlib import version
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\version.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .compat import string_types
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\compat.py", line 38, in <module>
    from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\HTMLParser.py", line 47, in <module>
    """, re.VERBOSE)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: nothing to repeat
```

I've also installed pip in C:\Python27\lib\site-packages.  However, when it is only installed in that directory PyScripter doesn't recognize that it is installed.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by doing a really CLEAN reinstall of python.

My version of ArcGIS has gone up and down from 10.2.2 to 10.3 to 10.2 to 10.2.2 again.  When ArcGIS (or just the Python features) is removed via Add/Remove Programs, most of the files from C:\Python27 will be removed.  However, this will not remove the python dll from your system folder.  Depending on your Window OS, it will be either:

- C:\Windows\System32\python27.dll
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\python27.dll

Remove the DLL manually, and then do the python install again.

This should give your a really clean install of python, then run your get-pip.py again, and pip should work as expected!

P.S. The removing of the dll is really important if you are downgrading your python.  As the python27.dll seem to get replaced if python is upgraded, but not when it is downgraded.  Hence, there is incompatibility between python27.dll with the scripts in C:\Python27.

Comment: This was dead on for me - saved hours of banging my head against the wall. On a machine that went from 10.2.2->10.3 and back to 10.2.2 again. Clearing the DLL in SysWOW64 and repairing the ArcGIS install fixed everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar setup (Python installed through ArcGIS 10.2, but on machines running Windows 7 not 8.1). I used PIP to install another package (birdy instead of scrapy) and got it working. I think your problem may be trying to work from inside a Python interpreter instead of from the command line (oh, ye mighty Unix users with your ever-powerful command line). Here's what worked for me:

1. Go to http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html
2. Download the get-pip.py file and place it in your python folder, e.g.: C:\python27\arcgis10.2\
3. Start a command prompt (Start Menu >> Accessories >> Command Prompt)
4. Change directories to python folder by entering:  cd c:\python27\arcgis10.2
5. Install PIP by entering:  python get-pip.py
6. Change directories into the scripts folder by entering: cd scripts
7. Use pip to install your package (e.g. scrapy) by entering: pip install scrapy

If this works, you should be able to go into Python now and import scrapy. This worked for me on every computer in my lab... just not on my own laptop... will be writing up my own question for that soon (arghh!).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm going to give it a try along with yageek's suggestion and see what works.  I appreciate the help greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the file `HTMLParser.py` as following (`C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\HTMLParser.py` for me):

Before :

```
locatestarttagend = re.compile(r"""
  <[a-zA-Z][-.a-zA-Z0-9:_]*          # tag name
  (?:[\s/]*                          # optional whitespace before attribute name
    (?:(?<=['"\s/])[^\s/>][^\s/=>]*  # attribute name
      (?:\s*=+\s*                    # value indicator
        (?:'[^']*'                   # LITA-enclosed value
          |"[^"]*"                   # LIT-enclosed value
          |(?!['"])[^>\s]*           # bare value
         )
       )?(?:\s|/(?!>))*
     )*
   )?
  \s*                                # trailing whitespace
""", re.VERBOSE)
```

After :

```
locatestarttagend = re.compile(r"""
  <[a-zA-Z][-.a-zA-Z0-9:_]*          # tag name
  (?:[\s/]*                          # optional whitespace before attribute name
    (?:(?<=['"\s/])[^\s/>][^\s/=>]*  # attribute name
      (?:\s*=+\s*                    # value indicator
        (?:'[^']*'                   # LITA-enclosed value
          |"[^"]*"                   # LIT-enclosed value
          |(?!['"])[^>\s]*           # bare value
         )
       )?(?:\s|/(?!>))*
     )*
   )  # >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Remove the ? <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  \s*                                # trailing whitespace
""", re.VERBOSE)
```

Then use `pip`. I don't know what would be affected by this modification. It may be safer to add the interrogativ point after you used `pip`

Comment: This worked for me, thank you @yageek.  Seems as though this modification is also needed for the `pip install <package>` command. I ended up replacing the '?' after installing the package because I am not sure the implications of the change on the HTMLParser script.

Comment: yageek, after i did what you suggested, and run "get pip" to install it, i got this result You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python27\arcgis10.3\lib\site-packages . what can i do now?