# how to install pip in ArcGIS-installed Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, arcgis

i want to install pip in ArcGIS-installed Python 2.7, so i

1. go to http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html, download the get-pip.py file and place it in my python folder, C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\,
2. start a command prompt (Start Menu >> Accessories >> Command Prompt)
   Change directories to python folder by entering: cd c:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2
3. Install PIP by entering: python get-pip.py

but it said "could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip  no matching distribution found for pip".

because i once install arcgis 10.3 and now use Arcgis 10.2., i found a solution in [Installing pip using ArcGIS-installed Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581838/installing-pip-using-arcgis-installed-python-2-7), it said i should remove the python27.dll manually, and then do the python install again.

After i follow this instruction, and repeat the pip installation again, the same problem occurred.

so, i really want to fix the problem and know the reason why. thank you.

Comment: finally, i update ArcGIS10.2 TO ArcGIS10.3, and follow the same steps mentioned before and the problem disappeared. so this problem may be from version match. but i still don' t know the specific problem.

Comment: I'd like to see an answer for ArcGIS10.2 and python 2.7.5 - best info is `https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2351`